# ProgressIndicator spends a lot of CPU in indeterminate mode (JavaFX)

Tags: javafx

My node shows the device that is connected to my PC. While it is not connected the progressIndicator in indeterminate mode (progress=-1) is shown (and message 'device is not turned on'). But I have problem with CPU usage - while progressIndicator is indeterminated the CPU usage is very hight (near 20%). When I turn on device the progressIndicator is hidden and the CPU usage becomes 1% or 2%. 
Even in this example with one progressIndicator in indeterminate mode I have CPU usage near 12%:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.CacheHint;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressIndicator;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Del extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Scene scene = new Scene(getTestGridPane());

        primaryStage.setTitle("Welcome to JavaFX!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.sizeToScene();
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public GridPane getTestGridPane() {
        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
        ProgressIndicator mp = new ProgressIndicator();
        mp.setCache(true);
        mp.setCacheHint(CacheHint.SPEED);
        mp.setCacheShape(true);

        gridPane.add(mp, 0, 0);
        return gridPane;
    }
}
```

How can I use the progressIndicator in indceterminate state for a long time?

Comment: The first time I ran your code, I saw on _Task Manager_ that CPU was at 80%. However the second and third and fourth time I ran your code, the CPU started at just over 10% but quickly dropped to 2%. I am using JDK 13.0.2 on Windows 10 64-bit.

Comment: Thanks for an answer! I use jdk 1.8.0_191 because it s connected with other old projects. I ll try to test in new JDK